# Is there any GTD or ToDo application that supports both Android and Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, android, sync

I am looking for a GTD or ToDo application for both Android and Ubuntu that provides following features:

1. Can be used simultaneously on both - Linux and Android with the option of automatic synchronization?
2. Could be shown on the desktop of Ubuntu or in the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

Evernote has its Ubuntu synchronization with tool named as everpad. as you know that Evernote is a very famous tool for notes and ToDO and that tool is everpad.

you can install everpad in Ubuntu by using these commands from your terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install everpad
```

[image]

[credit goes here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/use-evernote-in-ubuntu-with-everpad)

Comment: This is good idea but for some reason it doesn't work (load) for me. I have Zorin6 based on ubuntu. AWN is the main manager. Could that be a reason ?